# swift 3 capturing camera output as video

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10, video-capture

I have this code connecting the back camera on a device to a view on the UI, and I know how to capture photos.  How do I capture video from the camera and save/replay it, and vary the fps of the video I am capturing?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDuoCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera,AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.unspecified)
    for device in (deviceDiscoverySession?.devices)! {
        if (device as AnyObject).position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {
            do{
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device )
                if captureSession.canAddInput(input){
                    captureSession.addInput(input)
                    if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput){
                        captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)
                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                        captureSession.startRunning()
                    }
                }
            }
            catch{
                print("Error displaying camera data")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not post [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908427/swift-3-need-an-answer-to-these-2-questions) which only promote your other questions. If you are not receiving a response, consider improving questions by adding more relevant tags, more details, or by promoting the question elsewhere to draw attention to it. Posting non-questions is counterproductive and will eventually get you banned from asking anything at all, which is certainly not in your interest.

Comment: In that case what would you like me to add to this question to make it clearer?

Comment: At the very least some more related tags will put it in front of more people able to answer the question.